# How do I return an empty string in a Null property when converted to JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that returns a Customer object that is converted to JSON using the Json() method.

```
return Json(Repository.Customer.Get(id));
```

One of the properties of the Customer object is Customer.Gender. If the Gender property contains a Null value, the JSON object received on the client contains

```
Gender: "<null>"
```

Is there a way to have the properties with Null values contain empty strings in the JSON object rather than the "null" text?

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031088/how-to-avoid-null-strings-when-binding-json-data-on-client-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your Customer object properties?

```
public class Customer
{
  public string GenderOrEmptyString {get {return this._gender ?? ""; }
}
```

Comment: Yea, it would work but it is going to be a lot of work to make the changesince I use auto property declarations almost exclusively.