# Change Default JSON Serialization in ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, json, webforms, pagemethods

Well it can be done in MVC and WebAPI. But is there a way to change default serializer in ASP.Net Web Forms? We are using `Newtonsoft.JSON` to send objects over the wire. It uses `CamelCasePropertyName` so `FirstName` in C# becomes `firstName` in JSON. Now when we need to pass objects back to server for `web methods` to consume, we have to create new object with `FirstName` property instead of `firstName` otherwise ASP.Net complains and request fails.

I sincerely hope that there is something very easy and straight-forward that I'm missing.

**EDIT**:- Well that all is well and good to overcome these issues by implementing custom converts for types or by using web service or wcf or moving to MVC/WebAPI. What we are trying to achieve is by using page method with classic (if it is right to say so) ASP.Net web-forms.

I was looking for some way to plug in `JSON.Net` serializer (*Newtonsoft* one) in place of default `JavaScriptSerializer` as we can do in `MVC/WebAPI` stack.

Sample code:

```
//class
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
}

//WebMethod in ASPX code-behind
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateStudent(Student s)
{
    //code to update object and send some response back.
}
```

**MAIN ISSUE**

When getting data from browser in json format with camel case, default `JavaScriptSerialization` is not able to handle property names.

But if I send custom object like:

```
var o={FirstName:'John'};
```

it works!!!

Comment: Care to show example signature of your service method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement custom JSON serialization from ASP.NET web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159704/how-to-implement-custom-json-serialization-from-asp-net-web-service)

Comment: here is answer to your question [Pascal case dynamic properties with Json.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247478/pascal-case-dynamic-properties-with-json-net)

Comment: @AlekseyNosik It is already pascal cased when sending as I'm using `JSON.Net` to serialize objects. The issue is when browser is sending data to `PageMethod`, it is not able to properly convert properties from camel case to pascal case.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar it is `PageMethod` (or `WebMethod`). I've added sample code.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I understood, I didn't check it myself but according to description it doing exactly what you need

Comment: @AlekseyNosik yes it is definitely doing what I want. Only thing is that either there is no way to plug custom JSON serializer in webforms or I don't know about it at least yet :)

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot you wrote you are using Newtonsoft.JSON and answer is also about it, it's from description "JSON.NET already provides a ExpandoObjectConverter so with some little adjustments you have what you want."

Comment: @alekseynosik that is when I do serialisation, explicitly calling json. Net seeializer and send objects as string. The problem part is with reverse traffic, as. Net desirialises it automatically and fails. There is a way to bring strings and the desirialise but that will mean doing it manually in many places.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot as I understood you are trying to do it with JavaScriptSerialization class, I don't see any reason not to use JSON.NET here

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot sorry missed that you, explicitly calling json, it won't be easy for sure, I see only 3 ways to make it in easier way, first is to change input value to string, second is to move this logic to client and make similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931828/convert-returned-json-object-properties-to-lower-first-camelcase) and last one is simply to change your c# to firstName and so on

Answer (score 0):

Both C# and Javascript are case sensitive language. So FirstName and firstName treated differently.

If you don't want to use Newtonsoft.JSON then, You can use `DataContractJsonSerialize` to Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data into C# type. To do this you should have matching C# type.

Please check the following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx) links that will help you.

Comment: ummm, isn't that about WCF?

Comment: the serialization logic is standard logic and can be use in ASP.Net, MVC, WCF, c# etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in WCF (which would be my personal preference over page methods) and converters (agree on that - setting something complex like that for serialization of json is overkill), all left to do is hack:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateStudent(Dictionary<string, object> studentContent)
{
  // serialize generic json dictionary to json - once again :)
  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentContent);
  // now you have string you can "properly" deserialize
  var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(json);
  // ...
  return string.Empty;
}
```

Pretty much any json object can be described as `Dictionary<string, object>` where value can be of either string type or another `Dictionary<string, object>`.